# Pine script error: "Mismatched input 'to' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'." without indentation problem

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I got "Mismatched input 'to' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'." error. I have already checked my indentation.Here is my simple code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script",overlay=true)
n=55
s=0.0
s2=0.0
m=0.0
float[] r = na

for i=0 to n-1
    s:=s+close[i]
    r[i]=5

    
plot(s/n,color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `[]` in pine-script is not arrays. It is called [History Reference Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator). In order to use [arrays](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Arrays.html?highlight=array), you need to use appropiate functions.

Try this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script",overlay=true)
n=55
s=0.0
s2=0.0
m=0.0
r = array.new_float(n, na)

for i=0 to n-1
    s:=s+close[i]
    array.set(r, i, 5)
    
plot(s/n,color=color.red)
```